# Render React component with onClick and execute props function

Tags: reactjs

What I try to acheive is NOT JUST render a component by `onClick` but also pass a dynamic function to the component.

**Restrictions**
In the project there is [Dialog](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.58.0/components/dialog/definition?showCode=true&showRtl=false&showTransparent=false&showVariables=false#types-dialog) component from the FluentUI. This dialog has `open` property which is boolean and can be triggered by that. On one of the pages we lots of buttos which need to trigger the `<Dialog/>` this is why I can't just paste this sample code and change `open` state:

```js
<Dialog
    cancelButton={()=>{setOpen(false)}}
    confirmButton={handleOnclick}
    header="Action confirmation"
    open={open}
/>
```

**Requirements**:

- Dialog should be dynamic
- Must only be rendered when we press on some buttons
- Must execute function which is passed to it with `confirmButton`

**Simplified code**
Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-wave-4muvz?file=/src/App.tsx) to the sandbox. Here how it looks:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVis] = React.useState(false)
  const Component = ({id,execute}:{id:number,execute?:any}) =>{
    //this part here should stayed untouched
    return visible ? <button onClick={execute(id)}></button> : <></>
  }

  const handleClick = (id: number,execute: any)=>{
    setVis(true)
    return <Component id={id} execute={execute}/>
  }

  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <button onClick={()=>handleClick(1,(id:number)=>{console.log(id)})}>First</button>
      <button onClick={()=>handleClick(2,(id:number)=>{console.log(id)})}>Second</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The code tries to replicate my situation but more simple way. I'm trying to render a component which has a button to execute some code passed to it.
**Problem:** `Component` never displays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: React docs discourages storing components in state - not giving a reason though in the docs I found. So it's probably better just to store { id, execute } in state an pass them along to the component when rendering.

Like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVis] = React.useState<any>()
  const Component = ({id,execute}:{id:number,execute?:any}) =>{
    //this part here should stayed untouched
    return <button onClick={() => execute(id)}></button>
  }

  const handleClick = (id: number, execute: any)=>{
    setVis({ id, execute })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App" >
      { visible ? <Component id={visible.id} execute={visible.execute} /> : <div /> }
      <button onClick={()=>handleClick(1,(id:number)=>{console.log(id)})}>First</button>
      <button onClick={()=>handleClick(2,(id:number)=>{console.log(id)})}>Second</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

First revision of answer below:

When you call `handleClick` you return the component, you want rendered - but you don't actually render it. To render it you have to return the component as a part of the App-component's return value.

Like e.g.

```
  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <Component /* missing arguments here */ />
      <button onClick={()=>handleClick(1,(id:number)=>{console.log(id)})}>First</button>
      <button onClick={()=>handleClick(2,(id:number)=>{console.log(id)})}>Second</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Now you have two different "types of visible" components: Two different id's with different callbacks dependent on which button was clicked originally. And you have to store this information in `state` too. One way to do that is store these parameters as an object in state instead of just true/false.

But you can also just store the Component in state, like:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVis] = React.useState<any>()
  const Component = ({id,execute}:{id:number,execute?:any}) =>{
    //this part here should stayed untouched
    return <button onClick={() => execute(id)}></button>
  }

  const handleClick = (id: number, execute: any)=>{
    setVis(<Component id={id} execute={execute} />)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App" >
      { visible ? visible : <div /> }
      <button onClick={()=>handleClick(1,(id:number)=>{console.log(id)})}>First</button>
      <button onClick={()=>handleClick(2,(id:number)=>{console.log(id)})}>Second</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now I did have to change the part you wanted "untouched" for two reasons:

First of all, your onclick-callback was executed immediately upon rendering, so I wrapped it in a function. Secondly, the check for visible would always be true here, given that we just rendered the component - because it was truthy.

Comment: Thank you. Could you spread more for "One way to do that is store these parameters as an object in state instead of just true/false." with example?

Comment: Sure, i have edited it in. It's a better solution :)